# Istio adds and removed headers, but doesn't overwrite

Tags: istio

I am trying to add, overwrite and remove headers with `VirtualServices`, with Istio. Adding a header to the request and removing a header from the response works just fine, but it is not overwriting the header from the request.

So, according to Istio docs, headers operations are as follows:

[image]

And this is my `VirtualService`:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: server-vs
spec:
  hosts:
  - server.istio.svc.cluster.local
  http:
  - headers:
      request:
        set:
          test: "true"
        add:
          added: "header"
    route:
    - destination:
        host: server.istio.svc.cluster.local
        subset: apache
      weight: 90
    - destination:
        host: server.istio.svc.cluster.local
        subset: nginx
      headers:
        response:
          remove:
          - foo
      weight: 10
```

Focusing on `set` a header, this is my understanding. Istio is going to identify a header with key `test`, and it is going to overwrite the value by `true`. So, if I curl my service with `-H "test: hello"` parameter, I should see `test: true` in my request.

Now, I have tcpdump installed in my backend pod, and I can see `added: header`. I can also see that `foo: bar` has been removed (my nginx server is returning `foo: bar` along with the response), but I can't see `test: true` header. Is my understanding correct about header operations with Istio?

**From the tests:**

**REQUEST**

```
/ # curl -H "test: hello" server
<h1>THIS IS AN ISTIO DEMO</h1>/ #
```

**RESPONSE**

```
15:47:27.387891 IP 192.168.49.58.39652 > 192.168.113.134.80: Flags [S], seq 2810811797, win 28000, options [mss 1400,sackOK,TS val 1900372734 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
E..<d.@.>.....1:..q....P..........m`
3.....x...
qEb.........
15:47:27.388130 IP 192.168.49.58.39652 > 192.168.113.134.80: Flags [.], ack 2093848160, win 219, options [nop,nop,TS val 1900372735 ecr 3950379544], length 0
E..4d.@.>.....1:..q....P....|..`.....z.....
qEb..v..
15:47:27.388202 IP 192.168.49.58.39652 > 192.168.113.134.80: Flags [P.], seq 2810811798:2810812507, ack 2093848160, win 219, options [nop,nop,TS val 1900372735 ecr 3950379544], length 709: HTTP: GET / HTTP/1.1
E...d.@.>.....1:..q....P....|..`....S&.....
qEb..v..GET / HTTP/1.1
host: server
user-agent: curl/7.59.0
accept: */*
test: hello                  <-HERE IS THE HEADER THAT SUPPOSED TO BE OVERWRITTEN
x-forwarded-proto: http
x-request-id: 05ff2bb6-8810-9411-8a3b-7456066e1d16
x-envoy-decorator-operation: server-vs:80/*
x-istio-attributes: CjwKGGRlc3RpbmF0aW9uLnNlcnZpY2UuaG9zdBIgEh5zZXJ2ZXIuaXN0aW8uc3ZjLmNsdXN0ZXIubG9jYWwKOgoXZGVzdGluYXRpb24uc2VydmljZS51aWQSHxIdaXN0aW86Ly9pc3Rpby9zZXJ2aWNlcy9zZXJ2ZXIKJAoYZGVzdGluYXRpb24uc2VydmljZS5uYW1lEggSBnNlcnZlcgooCh1kZXN0aW5hdGlvbi5zZXJ2aWNlLm5hbWVzcGFjZRIHEgVpc3Rpbwo6Cgpzb3VyY2UudWlkEiwSKmt1YmVybmV0ZXM6Ly9jdXJsZXItNzU1Y2M3Y2ZmZi14dmxiMi5pc3Rpbw==
x-b3-traceid: 741c90fab1ca5e23802399916451563e
x-b3-spanid: 802399916451563e
x-b3-sampled: 1
added: header                <- HERE IS THE ADDED HEADER
content-length: 0


15:47:27.390857 IP 192.168.49.58.39652 > 192.168.113.134.80: Flags [.], ack 2093848436, win 228, options [nop,nop,TS val 1900372737 ecr 3950379547], length 0
E..4d.@.>.....1:..q....P...[|..t...........
qEc..v..
```

But I was expecting to see `test: true`

Comment: Hi suren , I tested it and in fact i couldn't make it work with request field, but i made it with response one, if You change it, it should work. The question now is, if that's the answer You we're looking for or You want to make it work with request field?

Comment: Yeah, I needed it in request headers. I posted the answer that solved the problem. Weird thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A silly thing solved the problem. Looks like if I define first `set` then `add`, in the yaml file, it doesn't work, but if I do it backwords, it works. I guess it's a bug. So the following yaml worked:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: server-vs
spec:
  hosts:
  - server.istio.svc.cluster.local
  http:
  - headers:
      request:
        add:                    <- add goes first
          added: "header"
        set:                    <- set goes second
          test: "true"
    route:
    - destination:
        host: server.istio.svc.cluster.local
        subset: apache
      weight: 90
    - destination:
        host: server.istio.svc.cluster.local
        subset: nginx
      headers:
        response:
          remove:
          - foo
      weight: 10
```