# Istio virtual service header rules are not applied

Tags: header, virtual, istio, gateway, mesh-network

So I have a very unique situation.
**Problem**
Virtual services route rules are not applied. We have a buzzfeed sso setup in our cluster. We wand to modify response headers to i.e Add header. to each request that matches the uri sign_in.
Buzzfeed sso has its own namespace.
Now To accomplish this I have created a virtual service.
**Steps to Reproduce**:
We used this virtual service spec to create the route rules.

```html
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: sso-auth-injector
spec:
  hosts:
  - sso-auth
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /sign_in
      ignoreUriCase: true
    route:
    - destination:
        host: sso-auth
      headers:
        response:
          add: 
            foo: bar
        request:
          add:
            hello: world
```

**Analysis**

Istioctk x describe has output
Pod: sso-auth-58744b56cd-lwqrh.sso
Pod Ports: 4180 (sso-auth), 15090 (istio-proxy)
Suggestion: add ‘app’ label to pod for Istio telemetry.
Suggestion: add ‘version’ label to pod for Istio telemetry.
Service: sso-auth.sso
Port: http 80/HTTP targets pod port 4180
Pod is PERMISSIVE (enforces HTTP/mTLS) and clients speak HTTP
VirtualService: sso-auth-injector.sso
/sign_in uncased
2) Istioctl . Not attaching all the rules but for outbound|80|

```
"routes": [
                    {
                        "match": {
                            "prefix": "/sign_in",
                            "caseSensitive": false
                        },
                        "route": {
                            "cluster": "outbound|80||sso-auth.sso.svc.cluster.local",
                            "timeout": "0s",
                            "retryPolicy": {
                                "retryOn": "connect-failure,refused-stream,unavailable,cancelled,resource-exhausted,retriable-status-codes",
                                "numRetries": 2,
                                "retryHostPredicate": [
                                    {
                                        "name": "envoy.retry_host_predicates.previous_hosts"
                                    }
                                ],
                                "hostSelectionRetryMaxAttempts": "5",
                                "retriableStatusCodes": [
                                    503
                                ]
                            },
                            "maxGrpcTimeout": "0s"
                        },
                        "metadata": {
                            "filterMetadata": {
                                "istio": {
                                    "config": "/apis/networking/v1alpha3/namespaces/sso/virtual-service/sso-auth-injector"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "decorator": {
                            "operation": "sso-auth.sso.svc.cluster.local:80/sign_in*"
                        },
                        "typedPerFilterConfig": {
                            "mixer": {
                                "@type": "type.googleapis.com/istio.mixer.v1.config.client.ServiceConfig",
                                "disableCheckCalls": true,
                                "mixerAttributes": {
                                    "attributes": {
                                        "destination.service.host": {
                                            "stringValue": "sso-auth.sso.svc.cluster.local"
                                        },
                                        "destination.service.name": {
                                            "stringValue": "sso-auth"
                                        },
                                        "destination.service.namespace": {
                                            "stringValue": "sso"
                                        },
                                        "destination.service.uid": {
                                            "stringValue": "istio://sso/services/sso-auth"
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                "forwardAttributes": {
                                    "attributes": {
                                        "destination.service.host": {
                                            "stringValue": "sso-auth.sso.svc.cluster.local"
                                        },
                                        "destination.service.name": {
                                            "stringValue": "sso-auth"
                                        },
                                        "destination.service.namespace": {
                                            "stringValue": "sso"
                                        },
                                        "destination.service.uid": {
                                            "stringValue": "istio://sso/services/sso-auth"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "requestHeadersToAdd": [
                            {
                                "header": {
                                    "key": "hello",
                                    "value": "world"
                                },
                                "append": true
                            }
                        ],
                        "responseHeadersToAdd": [
                            {
                                "header": {
                                    "key": "foo",
                                    "value": "bar"
                                },
                                "append": true
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
```

**Issues/Questions**

These rules dont take affect. Each request is passed to the service but headers are not modified.
Shouldnt the route rules be applicable to inbound requests as opposed to outbound (as shown in config generated).

Answer (score 0):

> We want to modify response headers to i.e Add header. to each request that matches the uri sign_in

I made an example, tested it and everything works just fine.

Check below vs, tests and whole example.

**Virtual service**

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: nginxvirt
spec:
  gateways:
  - mesh
  hosts:
  - nginx.default.svc.cluster.local
  http:
  - name: match
    headers:
      response:
        add:
          foo: "bar"
    match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /sign_in
    rewrite:
      uri: /
    route:
    - destination:
        host: nginx.default.svc.cluster.local
        port:
          number: 80
        subset: v1
```

---

**Everything you need for test**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: ubu1
spec:
  containers:
  - name: ubu1
    image: ubuntu
    command: ["/bin/sh"]
    args: ["-c", "apt-get update && apt-get install curl -y && sleep 3000"]

---

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx1
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: nginx1
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: nginx1
        app: frontend
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx1
        image: nginx
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        lifecycle:
          postStart:
            exec:
              command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "echo Hello nginx1 > /usr/share/nginx/html/index.html"]

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx
  labels:
    app: frontend
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: frontend   

---

apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: nginxvirt
spec:
  gateways:
  - mesh
  hosts:
  - nginx.default.svc.cluster.local
  http:
  - name: match
      headers:
      response:
        add:
          foo: "bar"
    match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /sign_in
    rewrite:
      uri: /
    route:
    - destination:
        host: nginx.default.svc.cluster.local
        port:
          number: 80
        subset: v1

---  

apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: nginxdest
spec:
  host: nginx.default.svc.cluster.local
  subsets:
  - name: v1
    labels:
      run: nginx1
```

---

**Test from ubuntu pod**

I used `curl -I` for displaying response headers

```
curl -I nginx/sign_in
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
server: envoy
date: Tue, 24 Mar 2020 07:44:10 GMT
content-type: text/html
content-length: 13
last-modified: Thu, 12 Mar 2020 06:52:43 GMT
etag: "5e69dc3b-d"
accept-ranges: bytes
x-envoy-upstream-service-time: 3
foo: bar
```

As you can see the foo:bar header is added correctly.

---

**Additional links for headers**

- https://istiobyexample.dev/response-headers/
- [Istio adds and removed headers, but doesn't overwrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59533472/istio-adds-and-removed-headers-but-doesnt-overwrite)
- [How to display request headers with command line curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3252851/how-to-display-request-headers-with-command-line-curl)

---

In your istioctl analyze I see you might have an 503 error

```
"retriableStatusCodes": [
                                    503
                                ]
```

**Additional links for 503 eror**

- https://istio.io/docs/ops/best-practices/traffic-management/#avoid-503-errors-while-reconfiguring-service-routes
- https://istio.io/docs/ops/common-problems/network-issues/#503-errors-after-setting-destination-rule
- [Accessing service using istio ingress gives 503 error when mTLS is enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54160215/accessing-service-using-istio-ingress-gives-503-error-when-mtls-is-enabled?rq=1)